# Join entries in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Here is my query:

```
query2 = "
INSERT INTO randomnusers 
  SELECT src_ip, vlan_id, video_id, area 
  from video_2 
  WHERE date_pl >= '2011-11-29 00:00' AND date_pl <= '2011-12-05 23:55' 
  as table1 right join (SELECT distinct src_ip, vlan_id 
                        from video_2 
                        WHERE date_pl >= '2011-11-29 00:00' 
                          AND date_pl <= '2011-12-05 23:55' 
                        order by rand() limit 50) 
  as table2 on table1.src_ip = table2.src_ip, table1.vlan_id = table2.vlan_id"
```

In video_2 table, each users (use the combination of src_ip and vlan_id to identify different users) have several entries about their downloading history.

Now I want to randomly choose 50 different users, list all their downloading history in a new table called randomnusers.

But this syntax has an error around "as table1" can anyone help me to check?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of `SELECT` statement is `SELECT t1.name, t2.salary FROM employee AS t1, info AS t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.name;`

```
query2 = "INSERT INTO randomnusers (
    SELECT src_ip, vlan_id, video_id, area 
    from video_2  AS table1

    right join (SELECT distinct src_ip, vlan_id 
                    from video_2 
                    WHERE date_pl >= '2011-11-29 00:00' 
                      AND date_pl <= '2011-12-05 23:55' 
                    order by rand() limit 50) 
        as table2 on table1.src_ip = table2.src_ip AND table1.vlan_id = table2.vlan_id
    WHERE date_pl >= '2011-11-29 00:00' AND date_pl <= '2011-12-05 23:55')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying putting parenthesis around your table1 select like this:

```
(SELECT src_ip, vlan_id, video_id, area 
from video_2 
WHERE date_pl >= '2011-11-29 00:00' AND date_pl <= '2011-12-05 23:55') as table1
```